# Get strange letters from Arabic alphabet when scrape an Arabic website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would to scrape this site: http://waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=1

but when I do I get characters like these ÇáÞÑÂä ÇáßÑíã .

This how looks my script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
BASE_URL = "http://waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=1" 
source = requests.get(BASE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml') 
print(soup)
```

I tried these things but don't work for me:

`source.encoding = 'utf-8'`

and this:

`source.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'`

also this:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, from_endocing='ISO-8859-1')`

​But none worked for me.

Comment: check out this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/8272698

Answer (score 1):

Use `urlopen` instead of `request`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

BASE_URL = "http://waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=1"
open = urlopen(BASE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open, 'lxml')
print(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Requests may get the encoding wrong. For this site we can get the correct encoding from the Source.

[image]

You can assign the encoding like `source.encoding='windows-1256'` before using `source.text` in BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests
BASE_URL = "http://waqfeya.com/book.php?bid=1"
source = requests.get(BASE_URL)
print(source.encoding)
print(source.apparent_encoding)
source.encoding='windows-1256'
print(source.text)
```

I was able to get all the Arabic characters properly.