# converting html+hex email address to readable string Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, hex, ascii, converters, email-address

I've been trying to find an online converter, or Python3 function, for conversion of email addresses in the html+hex format, such as:  %69%6efo ---> info

```
%69 : i
%6e : n
&#64 : @
(source: http://www.asciitable.com/)
```

...and so on..

All the following sites are not converting both hex and html codes combined in the "word":

```
https://www.motobit.com/util/charset-codepage-conversion.asp
https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/ascii-text-to-binary-converter
https://www.dcode.fr/ascii-code
http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/
https://mothereff.in/binary-ascii
```

I'd appreciate any recommendations.
Txs.

Answer (score 1):

Try `html.unescape()` or `HTMLParser#unescape`, depending on which version of Python you are using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/2675670

Since this is a mix of hex values and regular characters, I think we have to come up with a custom solution:

```
word = "%69%6efo"

while word.find("%") >= 0:
    index = word.find("%")
    ascii_value = word[index+1:index+3]
    hex_value = int(ascii_value, 16)
    letter = chr(hex_value)
    word = word.replace(word[index:index+3], letter)

print(word)
```

Maybe there's a more streamlined "Pythonic" way of doing this, but it works for the test input.

Comment: txs @Richard, it solved part of my question, related to html code... I still need to find a way for the rest of it, such as %69%6efo@&#....