# Python print ascii character in string instead of value

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I have a string `"hello&#91; World&#93;"` and I want to convert it to `"hello[World]"`

I tried something like this:

```
 a.encode("utf-8").decode("ascii")
```

I got back same string as input.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an XY question, are you trying to decode the html coded character set? https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import html
html.unescape("LASIX &#91;FUROSEMIDE&#93;")
```

This produces:

```
'LASIX [FUROSEMIDE]'
```