# How to remove 'amp;' and some error character when converting html to text using Python?

Tags: python, html, text, replace, file-conversion

I am trying to convert html to text. Upon inspection, there are "amp;" and other non text items being converted. I used replace () to try to manually remove these non text items, but it does not seems to work.

Here are my codes:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import glob
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html
import lxml.html.clean

filenames = glob.glob('C:\daily\d??????e.htm')
print(" ")
print(" Combine Daily...")
print(" ")

with open('combine.txt', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g)

for i in filenames:
    mylines = []  # Declare an empty list named mylines.
    print(i)

    with open(i,'rt') as myfile:    # Open txt for reading text data.
        myfile = myfile.string.replace("amp;", "")
        myfile = myfile.string.replace("</font></pre><pre><font size='1'>", "")

        with open('combine.txt', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as g:
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            writer.writerow([myfile])
```

Comment: You should include a minimal sample of the problematic markup and rework your [mcve] to operate on the markup sample instead of files. I see you are importing BeautifulSoup but not using it - why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)