# Is there a way to edit a string within a list when creating a function?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am creating a function in python 3 by pulling HTML text from yahoo finance and using regular expressions so that once I enter a ticker symbol, the name of the company is returned. I am able to do so, however, when importing the company 'Macy's, Inc.', ['Macy's Inc'] is returned. Here is what I have tried so far to remove the '&#x27' and replace it with "'":

[image: attempt 2]

[image: attempt 2]

Comment: Please post your code as plain text, not screenshots, so we can copy it and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension

```
return [x.replace('&#27;', "'") for x in name]
```

See also [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) for how to decode all HTML entities in a string, not just `&#27;`.