# How to POST data from Python and GET on Flask front-end

Tags: python, flask

My current problem is to connect frontend with backend. I have done all the data processing in **init**.py which at the end of file has a message which is a valid json containing data. Now I want to POST this data to the flask front end and GET the data in the frontend so that I can use this data to visualize something on index.html. I don't know how to POST from here as I have tried posting from init.py and it doesnt work.

File structure:

```
-Application
  -app
    -templates
      -index.html
    -__init__.py
    -routes.py
  -check.py
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes

#MESSAGE IS A JSON AND HAS DATA 

message=json.dumps(dicts)
```

routes.py:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')

@app.route('/getjson', methods = ['GET'])


def index():
    user = {'username': 'Me'}
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user)
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ title }} - Status Checker</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, Me!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

check.py:

```
from app import app
```

Adding this `r = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/getjson", json=message)`  to init.py gives me an error :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /getjson (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x04ED1250>: Failed to
establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would better load message inside the route, like below:

```
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Me'}
    message=json.dumps(dicts)
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user, message=message)
```

Then, you must add a jinja loop in your html, to show parts of the message structure. Let me know if you need help with that, adding some info about the message and what you want to be shown in html

Comment: Ok, so I moved my processing from init.py to routes.py and have the message in index(). How do I render the json in the html file now?

Comment: Take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906140/displaying-json-in-the-html-using-flask-and-local-json-file