# json data returned Response 14 bytes [200 OK] instead of displaying JSON data

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I am facing a problem where I can't display the json data onto the flask view. whenever I got the data and trying to display it on the view, I am not able to display the json data.

Instead of returning the data in json form it returns nothing but Response 14 bytes [200 OK]. Where am I doing it wrong? here's the code I have.

```
@app.route('/prediction', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    data1 = request.get_json()
    return render_template('index.html', data = jsonify(data1))
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>Prediction Test</head>
<body>

<div>{{data}}</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The response:

```
Prediction Test
<Response 14 bytes [200 OK]>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906140/displaying-json-in-the-html-using-flask-and-local-json-file), so I'll borrow the answer from there.

[`jsonify()` returns a response object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) and not a string (which is why you are getting the `<Response 14 bytes [200 OK]>`). Instead, try using `json.dumps(data1)`:

```py
import json

@app.route('/prediction', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    data1 = request.get_json()
    return render_template('index.html', data=json.dumps(data1))
```