# google api translation pandas char

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, google-translation-api

I am translating text with Google Translate API using Python.
I have a problem the characters returned, for example I have `&quot;` instead of `"`.

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html.unescape` method

For instance:

```
from html import unescape

if __name__ == '__main__':
    converted = unescape('&quot;')
    print(converted)
```

Output:

```
"
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed  ,  It is not something about UTF8 ?

Comment: Could you please test `html.unescape` with other examples? I believe it will parse to UTF-8