# JSON output to web from flask backend

Tags: python, json, flask

I have scraped json data from other web and want to out put to web, but in the backend of flask, it only return a list, just like: [{'aa':'bb', 'cc':'dd'}]. How do I turn it to be json format so js script on html able to get these json data from backend?

app.py:

```
url1 = requests.get('https://xxxxxxx/getJSON.aspx?jsontype=xxxx.aspx')
json_data = json.loads(url1.content.decode())
json_data = json.dumps(json_data)
json_data = json.loads(json_data)
return render_template('index.html', json_data=json_data)
```

html script:

```
<script>
const json_org = JSON.parse({{ json_data }});
    const json_data = json_org
    ;

    const output = document.getElementById('output');

    output.innerHTML = json_data;
</script>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'

const json_org = JSON.parse([{&#56;name&#56;: &#56;Current&#56;},...}])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string

Answer (score 0):

Add safe filter, this will help,

```
JSON.parse('{{ json_data |tojson | safe}}');
```