# How to decode an encoded email address with Python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, decode

What's the best way to decode the following string?
I have a few emails that are being encoded. A sample encoded email is below.

```
encoded_string = "I&#110;fo&#064;dov&#101;rhou&#115;er&#101;&#115;or&#116;.c&#111;m"
decoded_string = "Info@doverhouseresort.com"
```

Comment: Well, what format is it encoded in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use module html

```
import html
encoded_string = "I&#110;fo&#064;dov&#101;rhou&#115;er&#101;&#115;or&#116;.c&#111;m"
decoded_string = html.unescape(encoded_string)
```