# python decode the words beginning with &#xe such as '&#xe091;' and '&#xe3c4'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying scraping and meet an issue about the words shows as  `'&#xe091;'`and `'&#xe3c4;'`, i serach the whole network but there's no answer about how to decode it, so I come to here to ask for help, is there's any way to decode it?

Answer (score 1):

These words called "html entities". Searching use this name, you can find many methods to parse them in python. ([Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string))

```py
import html
print(html.unescape('&#xe091;&#xe3c4;'))
```

P.S. Unicode code point `U+E091` and `U+E3C4` are in `Private Use Area` of Unicode, these don't have any meaning unless someone defines it (e.g. webfonts).