# how to remove html encodings from a string in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have used the strip_tags function. It removes tags like `"<p>, <b>"`, etc but things like `"&nbsp; &ldquo;"` and other html encodings remain. How to remove them ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/5386938

Answer (score 0):

Pass the string to ‘unquote’ function

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
s = unquote(s)
```

Comment: See html.unescape

Comment: @mkalioby, it does not work

Comment: @JustinEzequiel, coool ! Thanks :D

Comment: This function decodes URL request escapes (the ones you find in URLs, of the form `%xx` - like "%20" for a space character), and not HTML escapes of the form `&...`. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and explanation