# Why xml file 'text string' looks encoded after writing with python?

Tags: python, xml, encoding, character-encoding, data-handling

I tried to open XML with notepad, word-pad and notepad++ but it looks encoded into some kind of hashtag strings. But it shows actual data when open with almost any browser like edge, Firefox, explorer. I don't know where i goes wrong. Here is the xml file before writing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<COUNTER_document totalnoofwords="393" totalnoofsentences="13" noofwordswithSWR="265" newspaper="daily_waqt" newsdate="02.12.14" filename="0001p.xml" domain="sports" classification="PD">

<headline>بنگلہ دیش کا زمبابوے کا ون ڈے سیریز میں 5-0 سے وائٹ واش</headline>

<body>میر پور(وقت نیوز) بنگلہ دیش نے 5 میچوں کی سیریز کےآ خری میچ میں بھی فتح حاصل کر کے سیریز میں وائٹ واش کر دیا،زمبابوے ایک میچ بھی نہ جیت سکا۔آخری میچ میں زمبابوے کے 129 رنز کا ہدف بنگال ٹائیگرز نے 24.3 اوورز میں 5 وکٹوں کے نقصان پر حاصل کر لیا۔بنگلہ دیش کے شیر بنگلہ سٹیڈیم میر پور میں کھیلے گئے آخری ایک روزہ میچ میں زمبابوے کے کپتان چکمبورا نے ٹاس جیت کے بینٹگ کا فیصلہ کیا جو ان کی ٹیم کیلئے ڈراؤنا خواب ثابت ہوا اور پوری ٹیم 30 اوورز میں 128 رنز بنا کر پویلین لوٹ گئی زمبابوے کی پہلی وکٹ 16 رنز پر گری جب سکندر رضا صرف 9 رنز بنا کر مشرقی مرتضی کی بال پر آؤٹ ہوئے اس کے بعد مساکد ازااور سباندا کی پارٹنرشپنے ٹیم کا سکور95 رنز تک پہنچا دیا ۔مساکدازا 52 رنز بنا کر جبیر الحسن کا شکار بنے جبکہ سباندا نے 37 رنز کی اننگز کھیلی اس کے بعد کئی بھی زمبابوے کا کھلاڑی جم کر نہ کھیل سکا۔بنگال ٹائیگرز کی جانب سے عمدہ باؤلنگ کے نتیجے میں کپتان چکمبورا سمیت 8 کھلاڑی ڈبل فیگر کراس نہ کر سکے ۔بنگلہ دیش کی جانب سے ایک روزہ میچوں میں ڈیبیو کرنے والے تیج السلام نے اپنے پہلے ہی میچ میں ہیٹرک کی اسلام نے 7 اوورز میں صرف 14 رنز دئے اور چار کھلاڑیوں کع آؤٹ کیا جبکہ شکیب الحسن نے 30 رنز دیکر 3 اور جبیر الحسن نے41 رنز دیکر2 کھلاڑیوں کو پویلین کی راہ دکھائی ۔ 128 رنز کے جواب میں بنگال ٹائیگرز نے بیٹنگ شروع کی مشکلات کا سامنا رہا ان کے بھی ابتدائی 3 کھلاڑی 47 رنز پر پویلین لوٹ گئے۔ تمیم اقبال 10، انعام الحق8 رنز بنا کر آؤٹ ہوئے،آل راؤنڈر شکیب الحسن بغیر کوئی رنز بنائیپویلین لوٹ گئے وکٹ کیپر مشفق الرحیم صرف 11 رنز بنا کر چتارہ کا شکار بن گئے۔محمد اللہ نے51 رنز کی میچ وننگ اننگز کھیلی جبکہ صابر رحمٰن13 رنز بنا کر ناٹ آؤٹ رہے۔ زمبابوے کی جانب سے چتارہ نے 3 اور پنیا نگارا نے 2 کھلاڑیوں کو آؤٹ کیا ۔فتح کے ساتھ بنگلہ دیش نے سیریز میں وائٹ واش کر دیا۔زمبابوے کی ٹیم کوئی میچ نہ جیت سکی،تیج السلام کو میچ کا بہترین ایوارڈ دیا گیا جبکہ سیریز کا بہترین کھلاڑی مشفق الرحیم کو قرار دیا گیا۔</body>

</COUNTER_document>
```

Here is the code i use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from googletrans import Translator
import glob
import time

path="D:\\Counter\\*.*"

#Access All the files from given folder
file_list = glob.glob(path)
print(file_list)

#Load each file at a time.
my_list=[]
for file in glob.glob(path):

 #Translate object
 translator = Translator()
 mytree = ET.parse(file)
 myroot = mytree.getroot()
 for urdu in myroot.iter('body'):
    content= urdu.text

 result = translator.translate(content, dest='zh-cn')
 time.sleep(5)

 final= translator.translate(str(result), dest='ur')
 time.sleep(5)
 
 urdu.text = str(final)
 mytree.write(file)
```

And here is the final result of xml encoded with some kind of hastag strings

```
<headline>&#1576;&#1606;&#1711;&#1604;&#1729; &#1583;&#1740;&#1588; &#1705;&#1575; &#1586;&#1605;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;&#1608;&#1746; &#1705;&#1575; &#1608;&#1606; &#1672;&#1746; &#1587;&#1740;&#1585;&#1740;&#1586; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; 5-0 &#1587;&#1746; &#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1657; &#1608;&#1575;&#1588;</headline>
<body>Translated(src=zh-CN, dest=ur, text=Translated(src=ur, dest=zh-cn, text=Mirpur (&#1608;&#1602;&#1578; &#1606;&#1740;&#1608;&#1586;) &#1576;&#1606;&#1711;&#1604;&#1729; &#1583;&#1740;&#1588; &#1606;&#1746; &#1662;&#1575;&#1606;&#1670; &#1605;&#1740;&#1670;&#1608;&#1722; &#1705;&#1740; &#1587;&#1740;&#1585;&#1740;&#1586; &#1705;&#1575; &#1570;&#1582;&#1585;&#1740; &#1605;&#1740;&#1670; &#1580;&#1740;&#1578; &#1705;&#1585; &#1587;&#1740;&#1585;&#1740;&#1586; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; &#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1657; &#1608;&#1575;&#1588; &#1705;&#1585; &#1583;&#1740;&#1575;&#1548; &#1586;&#1605;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;&#1608;&#1746; &#1575;&#1740;&#1705; &#1576;&#1726;&#1740; &#1605;&#1740;&#1670; &#1606;&#1729;&#1740;&#1722; &#1580;&#1740;&#1578; &#1587;&#1705;&#1575;&#1748; &#1576;&#1606;&#1711;&#1604;&#1729; &#1583;&#1740;&#1588; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; &#1570;&#1582;&#1585;&#1740; &#1585;&#1608;&#1586; &#1605;&#1604; &#1662;&#1608;&#1604; &#1705;&#1746; &#1588;&#1740;&#1585; &#1576;&#1606;&#1711;&#1604;&#1729; &#1575;&#1587;&#1657;&#1740;&#1672;&#1740;&#1605; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; &#1729;&#1608;&#1606;&#1746; &#1608;&#1575;&#1604;&#1746; &#1575;&#1606;&#1657;&#1585;&#1606;&#1740;&#1588;&#1606;&#1604; &#1605;&#1740;&#1670; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; &#1586;&#1605;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;&#1608;&#1746; &#1705;&#1746; &#1705;&#1662;&#1578;&#1575;&#1606; &#1670;&#1705;&#1605;&#1576;&#1608;&#1604;&#1575; &#1606;&#1746; &#1657;&#1575;&#1587; &#1580;&#1740;&#1578;&#1606;&#1746; &#1705;&#1575; &#1601;&#1740;&#1589;&#1604;&#1729; &#1705;&#1740;&#1575; &#1580;&#1608; &#1575;&#1606; &#1705;&#1740; &#1657;&#1740;&#1605; &#1705;&#1746; &#1604;&#1740;&#1746; &#1575;&#1740;&#1705; &#1672;&#1585;&#1575;&#1572;&#1606;&#1575; &#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1576; &#1578;&#1726;&#1575;&#1548; &#1657;&#1740;&#1605; &#1606;&#1746; 30 &#1605;&#1740;&#1670;&#1608;&#1722; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; 128 &#1662;&#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1606;&#1657;&#1587; &#1576;&#1606;&#1575;&#1574;&#1746;&#1748;&#1662;&#1726;&#1585; &#1608;&#1729; &#1662;&#1608;&#1740;&#1604;&#1740;&#1606; &#1604;&#1608;&#1657; &#1711;&#1574;&#1746;&#1748;&#1580;&#1576; &#1587;&#1705;&#1606;&#1583;&#1585; &#1585;&#1590;&#1575; &#1606;&#1746; &#1589;&#1585;&#1601; 9&#1662;&#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1606;&#1657;&#1587; &#1576;&#1606;&#1575;&#1574;&#1746;&#1548;&#1586;&#1605;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;&#1608;&#1746; &#1705;&#1740; &#1662;&#1729;&#1604;&#1740; &#1608;&#1705;&#1657; 16&#1662;&#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1606;&#1657;&#1587; &#1662;&#1585; &#1711;&#1585;&#1740;&#1748;&#1605;&#1585;&#1578;&#1590;&#1740;&#1648; &#1605;&#1585;&#1578;&#1590;&#1740;&#1648; &#1705;&#1740; &#1711;&#1740;&#1606;&#1583; &#1662;&#1585; &#1570;&#1574;&#1608;&#1657; &#1729;&#1608;&#1574;&#1746;&#1748;&#1605;&#1587;&#1575;&#1705;&#1575;&#1583;&#1586;&#1575; 52&#1662;&#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1606;&#1657;&#1587; &#1576;&#1606;&#1575; &#1705;&#1585; &#1580;&#1576;&#1740;&#1585; &#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1587;&#1606; &#1705;&#1575; &#1588;&#1705;&#1575;&#1585; &#1576;&#1606;&#1746; &#1580;&#1576; &#1705;&#1729; &#1587;&#1576;&#1575;&#1606;&#1672;&#1575; &#1606;&#1746; 37&#1575;&#1606;&#1606;&#1711;&#1586; &#1705;&#1726;&#1740;&#1604;&#1606;&#1746; &#1705;&#1746; &#1576;&#1593;&#1583; &#1586;&#1605;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;&#1608;&#1746; &#1705;&#1746; &#1705;&#1574;&#1740; &#1705;&#1726;&#1604;&#1575;&#1681;&#1740; &#1575;&#1740;&#1705; &#1587;&#1575;&#1578;&#1726; &#1705;&#1726;&#1740;&#1604;&#1606;&#1746; &#1587;&#1746; &#1602;&#1575;&#1589;&#1585; &#1585;&#1729;&#1746;&#1748; &#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1587;&#1604;&#1575;&#1605;&#1548; &#1575;&#1662;&#1606;&#1746; &#1608;&#1606; &#1672;&#1746; &#1672;&#1740;&#1576;&#1740;&#1608; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722;&#1548; &#1576;&#1606;&#1711;&#1604;&#1729; &#1583;&#1740;&#1588; &#1606;&#1746; &#1575;&#1662;&#1606;&#1746; &#1662;&#1729;&#1604;&#1746; &#1729;&#1740; &#1705;&#1726;&#1740;&#1604; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; &#1729;&#1740;&#1657; &#1657;&#1585;&#1705; &#1705;&#1740;&#1548; &#1575;&#1587; &#1606;&#1746; &#1589;&#1585;&#1601; 14 &#1576;&#1575;&#1585; &#1583;&#1608;&#1681; &#1604;&#1711;&#1575;&#1574;&#1740; &#1575;&#1608;&#1585; 4 &#1705;&#1726;&#1604;&#1575;&#1681;&#1740;&#1608;&#1722; &#1705;&#1608; &#1711;&#1585;&#1575;&#1740;&#1575;&#1548; &#1580;&#1576; &#1705;&#1729; &#1588;&#1705;&#1740;&#1576; &#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1587;&#1606; &#1606;&#1746; 3 &#1576;&#1575;&#1585; 30 &#1575;&#1608;&#1585; &#1580;&#1576;&#1740;&#1585; &#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1587;&#1606; &#1606;&#1746; 41 &#1576;&#1575;&#1585; &#1583;&#1608;&#1681; &#1604;&#1711;&#1575;&#1574;&#1740;&#1748; &#1548;2&#1705;&#1726;&#1604;&#1575;&#1681;&#1740;&#1608;&#1722; &#1705;&#1608; &#1662;&#1608;&#1740;&#1604;&#1740;&#1606; &#1705;&#1575; &#1585;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1729; &#1583;&#1705;&#1726;&#1575;&#1740;&#1575;&#1748;128&#1662;&#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1606;&#1657;&#1587; &#1705;&#1575; &#1587;&#1575;&#1605;&#1606;&#1575; &#1705;&#1585;&#1606;&#1746; &#1608;&#1575;&#1604;&#1746; &#1576;&#1606;&#1711;&#1575;&#1604;&#1586; &#1606;&#1746; &#1711;&#1740;&#1606;&#1583; &#1705;&#1608; &#1605;&#1575;&#1585;&#1606;&#1575; &#1588;&#1585;&#1608;&#1593; &#1705;&#1585; &#1583;&#1740;&#1575; &#1605;&#1588;&#1705;&#1604;&#1575;&#1578; &#1705;&#1575; &#1587;&#1575;&#1605;&#1606;&#1575; &#1705;&#1585;&#1578;&#1746; &#1729;&#1608;&#1574;&#1746; &#1575;&#1606; &#1705;&#1746; &#1657;&#1575;&#1662; 3&#1705;&#1726;&#1604;&#1575;&#1681;&#1740; &#1576;&#1726;&#1740; 47&#1662;&#1608;&#1575;&#1574;&#1606;&#1657;&#1587; &#1604;&#1746; &#1705;&#1585; &#1604;&#1608;&#1657;&#1746;&#1548; &#1578;&#1605;&#1740;&#1605; &#1575;&#1602;&#1576;&#1575;&#1604; 10&#1548; &#1575;&#1606;&#1593;&#1575;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1602; 8&#1585;&#1606;&#1586; &#1705;&#1746; &#1587;&#1575;&#1578;&#1726; &#1606;&#1605;&#1575;&#1740;&#1575;&#1722; &#1585;&#1729;&#1746;&#1748; &#1578;&#1605;&#1575;&#1605; &#1576;&#1575;&#1729;&#1585;. &#1570;&#1604; &#1585;&#1575;&#1572;&#1606;&#1672;&#1585; &#1588;&#1705;&#1740;&#1576; &#1575;&#1604;&#1581;&#1587;&#1606; (&#1705;&#1608;&#1574;&#1740; &#1606;&#1729;&#1740;&#1722;) &#1575;&#1587;&#1705;&#1608;&#1585; &#1606;&#1729;&#1740;&#1722; &#1705;&#1740;&#1575; &#1578;&#1726;&#1575;. &#1711;&#1608;&#1604; &#1705;&#1740;&#1662;&#1585; &#1605;&#1588;&#1601;&#1602; &#1585;&#1590;&#1740; &#1575;&#1604;&#1604;&#1729; &#1593;&#1606;&#1729; &#1606;&#1746; &#1575;&#1587;&#1746; (11) &#1575;&#1606;&#1729;&#1608;&#1722; &#1606;&#1746; &#1705;&#1729;&#1575; &#1705;&#1729; &#1705;&#1746; &#1576;&#1593;&#1583; &#1589;&#1585;&#1601; 11 &#1585;&#1606;&#1586; &#1604;&#1608;&#1657; &#1570;&#1574;&#1746;. &#1575;&#1587; &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; &#1705;&#1575;&#1605;&#1740;&#1575;&#1576; &#1729;&#1608;&#1711;&#1740;&#1575; &#1575;&#1608;&#1585; &#1576;&#1575;&#1729;&#1585; &#1657;&#1726;&#1729;&#1585;&#1746; &#1585;&#1729;&#1746;. &#1605;&#1740;&#1722; &#1586;&#1605;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;&#1608;&#1746;&#1548; Chatara 3 &#1608;&#1705;&#1657;&#1608;&#1722; &#1580;&#1740;&#1578; &#1705;&#1585; &#1587;&#1746; Panya &#1606;&#1575;&#1711;&#1585; 2 &#1580;&#1740;&#1578; &#1604;&#1740;&#1575; &#1608;&#1705;&#1657;&#1740;&#1722;&#1548; &#1575;&#1587; &#1601;&#1578;&#1581; &#1705;&#1746; &#1587;&#1575;&#1578;&#1726; &#1729;&#1740; &#1576;&#1606;&#1711;&#1604;&#1729; &#1583;&#1740;&#1588; &#1606;&#1746; &#1587;&#1740;&#1585;&#1740;&#1586; &#1575;&#1662;&#1606;&#1746; &#1606;&#1575;&#1605; &#1705;&#1585; &#1604;&#1740;&#1548; &#1586;&#1605;&#1576;&#1575;&#1576;&#1608;&#1746; &#1606;&#1746; &#1705;&#1608;&#1574;&#1740; &#1576;&#1726;&#1740; &#1605;&#1740;&#1670; &#1606;&#1729;&#1740;&#1722; &#1580;&#1740;&#1578;&#1575;&#1548; &#1605;&#1588;&#1601;&#1602; &#1575;&#1604;&#1585;&#1581;&#1740;&#1605; &#1705;&#1608; &#1705;&#1726;&#1740;&#1604; &#1705;&#1575; &#1576;&#1729;&#1578;&#1585;&#1740;&#1606; &#1705;&#1726;&#1604;&#1575;&#1681;&#1740; &#1602;&#1585;&#1575;&#1585; &#1583;&#1740;&#1575; &#1711;&#1740;&#1575;&#1748;, &#1578;&#1604;&#1601;&#1592;=[[], []], extra_data=" {'translat..." ), pronunciation=None, extra_data="{'translat...")</body>
</COUNTER_document>
```

Comment: Those are [html numeric entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/3439404) could help?