# Python problem with accents when decoding from base64

Tags: python, base64, decode

I'm getting data from a website and this is an example of a sentence I retrieved : `PHA+Q29ycmlnJmVhY3V0ZTtzIGV4ZXJjaWNlcyBlbnRyYWluZW1lbnQgY2hhcGl0cmUgbW91dmVtZW50IGV0IGZvcmNlczwvcD4K`

The sentence is encoded with base64 so I thought about decoding it and then encoding it back to utf-8 with python :

```py
import base64

sentence = "PHA+Q29ycmlnJmVhY3V0ZTtzIGV4ZXJjaWNlcyBlbnRyYWluZW1lbnQgY2hhcGl0cmUgbW91dmVtZW50IGV0IGZvcmNlczwvcD4K"
base64.b64decode(sentence).decode("utf-8")
```

The problem is that instead of looking like this: `"Corrigés exercices entrainement chapitre mouvement et forces"`, it looks like this: `"Corrig&eacute;s exercices entrainement chapitre mouvement et forces"`.

As you can see, the accents are completely messed up.

I'm using **python 3**

I do not have access to the decoded sentence using the API (I only have the base64 encoded one).

Thanks for you help.

Comment: You are correctly getting the plaintext from the Base64. However, that plaintext contains HTML entities; see [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone doesn't know about HTML entities (just like me) and needs the answer.

Thanks to Amadan's comment, I just learned that the strange thing I got instead of my accent was called an HTML entity.

In order to get back my accent, I needed to unescape it :

```py
import html

print(html.unescape("Corrig&eacute;s exercices entrainement chapitre mouvement et forces"))
```

`>> Corrigés exercices entrainement chapitre mouvement et forces`