# Python: how to replace html characters &lt; with < and &gt; with > in a Python list

Tags: python, list

I have a reference list containing function names in this format:

```
list_1_ref = ['Name1<abc>' , 'Name2<abc>']
```

From another function I get a return list containing elements with html format:

```
list_2 = ['Name1&lt;abc&gt;' , 'Name2&lt;abc&gt;']
```

My code should now compare if an element from `list_2` is contained in the first list:

```
for element in list2:
    if element in list_1_ref:
        # ...do something...
```

Unfortunately this does not work, I guess because of the html characters `&lt;` and `&gt;`.
What is an efficient method so solve this? I thought of a replacement, but my Python skills are limited and I am not sure how to do this and if it is the most efficient way.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) on your second list to compare the strings with the conversion applied:

```
import html


for html_element in list_2:
    element = html.unescape(html_element)
    if element in list_1_ref:
        # ...
```

How does the output of `html.unescape` look?

```
>>> html.unescape('Name1&lt;abc&gt;')
'Name1<abc>'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help! That solved my issue! :-)