# How to parse HTML document with &lt; and &gt using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have mutliple HTML documents that I need to parse for a very specific attribute in the HTML document, but I am not use to the HTMl documents having < and &gt for tags. I know they represent < and > for the tag, but I am seeing if anyone knows how to deal with these issue.

Snippet of the HTML doc:

```
&lt;score_result&gt;
            &lt;Models&gt;
                &lt;Model&gt;
                    &lt;Id&gt;CLASS&lt;/Id&gt;
                    &lt;Description&gt;Classifier Model 2.0&lt;/Description&gt;
                    &lt;Score&gt;613&lt;/Score&gt;
                    &lt;Messages&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;017111&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;# of bananas, S&amp;amp;Accounts Established&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;P11P&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;Absence of Banana&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;0111&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;Presence of a Banana&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;0111&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;# of Inquiries&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                    &lt;/Messages&gt;
                &lt;/Model&gt;
            &lt;/Models&gt;
        &lt;/score_result&gt;
```

I am specifically just trying to grab the Score value, `&lt;Score&gt;613&lt;/Score&gt;` from these HTML documents.

I first take my dataframe and put it into a tuple to iterate through each HTML document, create a BeautifulSoup Object, then try to find the tag with `.find_all()`.

I get an empty string every time. I considered also using regex but wanted to see what other people think.

My code:

```
result = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(df['ID'], df['data'])]

Score_lst = []

for row in result:
    try: 
        Bs_data = BS(row[1])
        Score_lst.append(Bs_data.find_all('score'))
    

    except:
        print('Na')
```

Expected Output:

```
Score_lst 

[613,
...,
...,
....]
```

The ... will be the other values I will parse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: `&lt;` and `&gt;` do not represent tags. You need to decode the html entities to get a valid html and then run beautifulsoup on that.

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can do to decode the html entities. Much Appreciated

Comment: JonSG, it does but BeautifulSoup version 4, doesn't have then convertEntities parameter so working around that, thank you for the insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve this conundrum:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
&lt;score_result&gt;
            &lt;Models&gt;
                &lt;Model&gt;
                    &lt;Id&gt;CLASS&lt;/Id&gt;
                    &lt;Description&gt;Classifier Model 2.0&lt;/Description&gt;
                    &lt;Score&gt;613&lt;/Score&gt;
                    &lt;Messages&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;017111&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;# of bananas, S&amp;amp;Accounts Established&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;P11P&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;Absence of Banana&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;0111&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;Presence of a Banana&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                        &lt;Message&gt;
                            &lt;MessageType&gt;RC&lt;/MessageType&gt;
                            &lt;Code&gt;0111&lt;/Code&gt;
                            &lt;Description&gt;# of Inquiries&lt;/Description&gt;
                        &lt;/Message&gt;
                    &lt;/Messages&gt;
                &lt;/Model&gt;
            &lt;/Models&gt;
        &lt;/score_result&gt;

'''

soup = bs(bs(html, 'html.parser').text, 'html.parser')
score = soup.select_one('Score')
print('And here is your score:', score.text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
And here is your score: 613
```