# How to convert/format characters with python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm actually trying to retrieve the title of a webpage with curl.
I'm using this code :

```
curl "%URLLink%" --insecure -L > "%HTMLFile%"
```

But I get some unformatted characters and it shows me something like this

```
<title> La guerre de l&#039;info : Israël / Hamas en replay - Complément d&#039;enquête </title>
```

instead of

```
<title> La guerre de l'info : Israël / Hamas en replay - Complément d'enquête </title>
```

I would like to have a simple way to make this understandable in a simple line code like this

```
curl "%URLLink%" --insecure -L | python -m json.tool > "%JSONFile%"
```

that I use to prettify some text in JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: Hi @JonSG, I success with creating a python file
```
import html
title = 'La guerre de l&#039;info : Israël / Hamas en replay - Complément d&#039;enquête'
print(html.unescape(title))
```

Is it possible to pipe it to convert directly from my curl command to save it into an already encoded file ?

Comment: I originally viewed this post as a duplicate, but after reading it a second time I realized the piping part was not addressed. I've never dont this myself, but it seems possible you could create a module yourself to facilitate this. I imagine it would be like 5 lines of code and a pip command but I bet you can find posts with proper instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Use html.unescape():

```
import html
print(html.unescape('l&#039;'))
```

It works for me