# Decoding response while opening a URL

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, urllib2

I am using the following code to open a url and retrieve it's response :

```
def get_issue_report(query):
    request = urllib2.Request(query)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response_headers = response.info()
    print response.read()
```

The response I get is as follows :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:issues='http://schemas.google.com/projecthosting/issues/2009' gd:etag='W/&quot;DUUFQH47eCl7ImA9WxBbFEg.&quot;'><id>http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/2</id><published>2008-08-30T16:00:21.000Z</published><updated>2010-03-13T05:13:31.000Z</updated><title>Testing if chromium id works</title><content type='html'>&lt;b&gt;What steps will reproduce the problem?&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;b&gt;1.&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;b&gt;2.&lt;/b&gt;
&lt;b&gt;3.&lt;/b&gt;

&lt;b&gt;What is the expected output? What do you see instead?&lt;/b&gt;


&lt;b&gt;Please use labels and text to provide additional information.&lt;/b&gt;
 </content><link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/2/comments/full'/><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/2'/><author><name>rah...@google.com</name><uri>/u/@VBJVRVdXDhZCVgJ%2FF3tbUV5SAw%3D%3D/</uri></author><issues:closedDate>2008-08-30T20:48:43.000Z</issues:closedDate><issues:id>2</issues:id><issues:label>Type-Bug</issues:label><issues:label>Priority-Medium</issues:label><issues:owner><issues:uri>/u/kuchhal@chromium.org/</issues:uri><issues:username>kuchhal@chromium.org</issues:username></issues:owner><issues:stars>4</issues:stars><issues:state>closed</issues:state><issues:status>Invalid</issues:status></entry>
```

I would like to get rid of the characters like &lt, &gt etc. I tried using

> response.read().decode('utf-8')

but this doesn't help much.

Just in case, the response.info() prints the following :

```
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=entry
Expires: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 11:15:17 GMT
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 11:15:17 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Vary: Accept, X-GData-Authorization, GData-Version
GData-Version: 1.0
ETag: W/"DUUFQH47eCl7ImA9WxBbFEg."
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 Mar 2010 05:13:31 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Connection: close
```

Here's the URL : https://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/2

Comment: You can't decode via `decode('utf-8')` because those are not unicode *code points* but HTML escaped characters! :) [others have already answered to how properly decode them, I just wanted to explain *why*...]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I unescape HTML entities in a string in Python 3.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1)

Comment: Mac/Sentinel, Thanks for the quick and great response! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2


query="http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/2"

def get_issue_report(query):
    request = urllib2.Request(query)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response_headers = response.info()
    return response.read()

s = get_issue_report(query)

p = HTMLParser()

print p.unescape(s)

p.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Sentinel has explained how you can decode entity references like `&lt;` but there's a bit more to the problem than that.

The example you give suggests that you are reading an Atom feed. If you want to do this reliably in Python, then I recommend using Mark Pilgrim's [Universal Feed Parser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/).

Here's how one would read the feed in your example:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> d = feedparser.parse('http://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/2')
>>> len(d.entries)
1
>>> print d.entries[0].title
Testing if chromium id works
>>> print d.entries[0].description
<b>What steps will reproduce the problem?</b>
<b>1.</b>
<b>2.</b>
<b>3.</b>

<b>What is the expected output? What do you see instead?</b>


<b>Please use labels and text to provide additional information.</b>
```

Using `feedparser` is likely to be much more reliable and convenient than trying to do your own XML parsing, entity decoding, date parsing, HTML sanitization, and so on.

Comment: Gareth, Thanks! I should try this. It looks a better option.

Comment: Unfortunately, even feedparser is unable to convert _all_ HTML entities like quot etc. Moreover, I am unable to add feedparser to my build path environment in Eclipse with PyDev plugin. Therefore, HTMLParser is the best option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use

xml.sax.saxutils.unescape()

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html#module-xml.sax.saxutils

Comment: Is this the "Best" solution? There would be certain characters which may go unescaped. I would like to decode the data as I open the URL and rather not "process" it later.

Comment: obviously your URL returns the data *exactly* that way.

Comment: How should we know? Give us the URL :)

Comment: When I use the JSON format I receive the data in a proper unicode format https://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/2?alt=json

Comment: Check this URL for XML https://code.google.com/feeds/issues/p/chromium/issues/full/2

There's a drastic difference in the output formats between both.