# How to output XML entity references

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using Python xml.etree.ElementTree to output XML.  I want to output it with entity references that will be substituted when the XML is parsed.

ordinarily '&' is escaped as `&amp;` because '&' is used to declare entity references.  However, I *really do* want to write an entity reference.  For example, I want to write an XML file containing the entity reference `&manifestName;`:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring
>>> manifest = Element('manifest')
>>> manifest.text = '&manifestName;'
>>> tostring(manifest)
```

Which returns an escaped ampersand:

```
'<manifest>&amp;manifestName;</manifest>'
```

The desired XML would be:

```
'<manifest>&manifestName;</manifest>'
```

I have tried various escaping tricks, like `&#38;`, `\&`, `&&`, but they do not work.  The ampersands they contain are always rendered as `&amp;`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to go with a relatively palatable hack.  In the text, I use `&&` to mean an escaped `&`.  ElementTree converts this to `&amp;&amp;`.  At the end, I simply do a string replacement on it:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring
>>> manifest = Element('manifest')
>>> manifest.text = '&&manifestName;'
>>> tostring(manifest).replace('&amp;&amp;', '&')
```

The result is the entity reference I want:

```
'<manifest>&manifestName;</manifest>'
```

Comment: I am having trouble implementing your solution. Could you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892938/xml-line-break-character-entity-and-python-encoding