# ElementTree's .write() changes strings with &quot; to &amp;quot;

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, html-entities, character-entities

In my code, I am changing an existed formatted string in XML with predefined format with ElementTree in Python.

```
<Value xsi:type='xs:string'>{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Test123&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;}</Value>
```

New text adding by: `ValueNode.text  = '{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;NewTextdemo&quot;}'`

and to save the file I am using `doc.write(path_to_XML_file)`

The problem is, that the `doc.write(path_to_XML_file)` is changing the `&quot;` to `&amp;quot;` further entity name -  and so the result XML is invalid.

Does anybody know how to avoid it? How to set write function to omits conding these special characters?

Thank you

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/7986272/407651

Comment: I would not expect `&quot;` to be changed to `&amp;quot;`, since `quot` is a predefined entity in XML. `manifestName` on the other hand (see the linked question) is not a predefined entity.

Comment: Dear @mzjn, I wouldn´t expext it either, because characer " is not converted by wirte function, so I don´t know why & is. The problem is not when assining new string to variable - there it works fine. The problem is with write() function. This function breaks the string.

Comment: `&` is replaced with `&amp;` in this function in ElementTree.py: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1033.

Comment: Dear @mzjn thank you. So it seems it's by design :-(