# How to get the ElementTree.toString method to output a non breaking space (nbsp)?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, html-entities, celementtree

How can I get the ElementTree.toString method to output `&nbsp;` from a node's text attribute?

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

node = ET.Element("node")
node.text = "hello&nbsp;there"
print(ET.tostring(node, encoding = 'utf8', method = "xml", xml_declaration = False).decode('utf8'))
```

outputs:

```
<node>hello&amp;nbsp;there</node>
```

But I would like it to recognise the `&nbsp;` entity and output:

```
<node>hello&nbsp;there</node>
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/7986272/407651

Comment: Note that `<node>hello&nbsp;there</node>` on its own is not a well-formed XML document since it contains no definition of the `nbsp` entity.