# Replacing HTML representation to ascii using Python

Tags: python, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

I have parsed some HTML text. But some punctuations like apostrophe are replaced by `&#8217;`. How to revert them back to  `

P.S: I am using Python/Feedparser

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1

Comment: `feedparser` parses `&#8217;` perfectly fine for me. What are you parsing, and how are you using `feedparser` to parse it?

Answer (score 1):

The PSF Wiki has some ways of doing it.  Here is one way:

```
import htmllib

def unescape(s):
    p = htmllib.HTMLParser(None)
    p.save_bgn()
    p.feed(s)
    return p.save_end()
```

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
import HTMLParser

hparser=HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
new_text=hparser.unescape(raw_text)
```