# use of \x27 to convert to apostrophe not working in python

Tags: python, html, apostrophe

I tried taking some data from the web:

Example:the name `'Schindler's list'` is printed as `'Schindler&#x27s List'` straight from the web... tried asking python to print `'Schindler\x27s list'` instead so that it would give me `'Schindler's list'`. But it didn't work.

What do I do?

P.S. This string is one of the many elements in a list and I did the same operation on many other strings in the list as well.

Comment: Is that even valid XML/HTML? Doesn't the `&#x27` require a semicolon afterwards?

Comment: You most likely want to know how to unescape HTML entities; which makes this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python

Comment: yes... forgot to mention.. it had a semicolon too.. but tried removing all of that and made it print Schindler\x27 list

Comment: Can this be marked as answered some way? I came across this looking for unanswered questions. @melony, maybe cut and paste a working code fragment in an answer you yourself provide?