# Weird (or not?) encoding migrating from an old Access Database to django

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, character-encoding

I'm trying to migrate a very old MS Access Database to django/mysql. I exported the data in csv-format using a very slow virtual machine which hosts the old database. I'm now trying to write a script that automatically inserts the data from the csv's into MySQL via Django, but I'm running into some issues which probably stem from me not entirely understanding the encoding or encoding in general.

It's a database in wich a lot of the text is in french, so it contains accented characters next to the usual html encoded quotation marks, etc. I was trying to just use the htmlparser approach from over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360639/278205), but it fails with a UnicodeDecodeError on strings like `Chaussée d'Enghien 16`. Which if you `od -c`  gives:

```
0000000    C   h   a   u   s   s 351   e       d   &   #   3   9   ;   E
0000020    n   g   h   i   e   n       1   6  \n
```

and `od -t xC`gives:

```
0000000    43  68  61  75  73  73  c3  a9  65  20  64  26  23  33  39  3b
0000020    45  6e  67  68  69  65  6e  20  31  36  0a
```

Checking the Access database again, it shows up the same there as the octal dump here: the actual string has the `é` as one character and the `&#39;` part as five.

How could I get these kinds of strings into the right encoding? Is this possible with a magical python function? Or is it beter to export the data in another format from the access database?

EDIT: 
Buried deep within Access, I found the option to export to utf-8, but no cigar.

Also, it seems that unicode decoding only doesn't work when the string contains a special character *and* a html escaped character.

Comment: Could you export from Access in UTF-8?

Comment: I can't do that directly, I think. I just tried exporting to xlsx and then from there to csv which I saved in text editor in utf-8. Still nothing...

Comment: Ha. SO I found the option for utf8 export buried deep in Access. I did it, but still the same UnicodeDecodeError on the same string

Comment: Could you give us a hex dump of the same part of the file, from the UTF8-encoded version?  Use `od -t xC`, please.

Comment: I've added it to my question.