# urllib.urlretrieve encoding is not kept

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm using python 3.4.

When I use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename="file.html")` on a utf-8 file, the resulting file.html is not properly encoded. How do I make sure the file is encoded using utf-8?
How to implement the .decode(utf-8) in this case?

### EDIT

This is the original part of page:

> « Écoute, mon peuple, je parle ; 
> Moi, Dieu, je suis ton Dieu ! 
> Je ne t'accuse pas pour tes sacrifices ; 
> tes holocaustes sont toujours devant moi. 
> « Je ne prendrai pas un seul taureau de ton domaine, 
> pas un bélier de tes enclos. 
> Tout le gibier des forêts m'appartient 
> et le bétail des hauts pâturages. 
> « Si j'ai faim, irai-je te le dire ? 
> Le monde et sa richesse m'appartiennent. 
> Vais-je manger la chair des taureaux 
> et boire le sang des béliers ? 
> « Qu'as-tu à réciter mes lois, 
> à garder mon alliance à la bouche, 
> toi qui n'aimes pas les reproches 
> et rejettes loin de toi mes paroles ? »

And this is what I get in the saved file:

> � �coute, mon peuple, je parle ;�
> Moi, Dieu, je suis ton Dieu !�
> Je ne t'accuse pas pour tes sacrifices ; 
> tes holocaustes sont toujours devant moi.�
> � Je ne prendrai pas un seul taureau de ton domaine, 
> pas un b�lier de tes enclos.�
> Tout le gibier des for�ts m'appartient 
> et le b�tail des hauts p�turages. 
> � Si j'ai faim, irai-je te le dire ? 
> Le monde et sa richesse m'appartiennent.�
> Vais-je manger la chair des taureaux 
> et boire le sang des b�liers ?�
> � Qu'as-tu � r�citer mes lois,�
> � garder mon alliance � la bouche,�
> toi qui n'aimes pas les reproches 
> et rejettes loin de toi mes paroles ?��

I noticed that in certain parts of the page accented characters are not really utf-8 encoded but the browser shows it properly. For example instead of `É` there is `&Eacute;` and when the file is downloaded this seems to cause problems.

Comment: I don't think `urlretrieve` re-encodes anything. Can you give an example?

Comment: It's called HTML escaping, not encoding. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2360598/1258041 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2087370/1258041

Comment: Thanks. How to I implement HtmlParser in my code above?

Comment: Take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unescape the HTML escape sequences in the file line by line using the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/1258041).

```
import html.parser
h = html.parser.HTMLParser()
with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as fin, open(
           "file.html", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(h.unescape(line.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: I tried this code and it does something but not exactly what I needed. Indeed the text is unescaped but the resulting file is saved in windows-1252 encoding, even the lines in the original that were not escaped.

Comment: @ToDo Try specifying `encoding` in the call to `open` as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: That did the trick. I must figure out how to create a function to use this code for each link I download in this script.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use it handle this for you: It convert the loaded document implecitly to utf-8

```
markup = "<h1>Sacr\xc3\xa9 bleu!</h1>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
soup.h1
# <h1>Sacré bleu!</h1>
soup.h1.string
# u'Sacr\xe9 bleu!'
```

BeautifulSoup documentation: [here](http://bit.ly/1lX6Qln)