# Repeatedly getting "302 Not found" Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip

When I run the following code

```
import socket
import urlparse
import re
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect(("www.google.co.in", 80))
s.send("GET /?gfe_rd=cr&amp;gws_rd=cr HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
data = s.recv(100000)
print data
s.close()
```

The response I get from google is always the following

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
Date: Mon, 04 Jan 2016 04:30:53 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 245
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: NID=75=chG9KySsUncl-1elqXhs56m7cNHxFvFwNR5pZoavIwRJ2PpoGlm5RbShdsiF7udrTgwZgG-eRo4oQqA0RhbfwtExcxUGk88F_R2TNV9vi4XKhWSB9ihhcqulYTtg9xGkagSDPdFfmw; expires=Tue, 05-Jul-2016 04:30:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;gws_rd=cr">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I understand this is because I did not follow the redirects. Could someone explain which url I should connect to so that I do not get this error, or how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `302 Found`, not a `Not Found`.

What `302` response code means is a redirect, something which your browser would silently/automatically do, and load the new redirect page.

As you can see in the response body

```
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;gws_rd=cr">here</A>.
```

Point your request to this URL, and you should no longer receive a `302` response, and **make sure you replace `&amp;` with `&`**:

```
s.send("GET /?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
```

Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360639/276949) to automatically unescape these URL's, so you don't need to do it manually.

For example, in Python 3.5:

```
import html
html.unescape('/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;gws_rd=cr')  # /?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=cr
```

Comment: Even when I do that I cannot seem to get the correct response

Comment: What's the response now? I get a `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` with your fixed code.

Comment: I get a 200 ok response but I cannot seem to get this to work with other websites like `www.cplusplus.com` (in the connect parameter), the response code is 301 (saying moved permanently)

Comment: Is this an assignment? Is there any reason you aren't using `Requests` for this: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ It would be a simple `requests.get('http://www.google.co.in')`

Comment: Yep.. it is an assignment

Comment: I see - well a 301 is similar to a 302. One is a temporary redirect, and one is permanent.  Make sure you are reading the `headers` that are returned right before the body. There will be one header named `Location` that tells you exactly where the redirect is to.

Comment: What was your original address? I see that `http://cplusplus.com/` 301 redirects to `http://www.cplusplus.com/`

Comment: I called the connect() function to "www.cplusplus.com"

Comment: Make sure your `GET /xxx` is correct as well. In this case it should be `/`

Comment: It is.. The top line is `GET / HTTP/1.1\n`. Could you get the request to work?

Comment: It seems you need to send the `Host` header as well for that website. `s.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n")
s.send("Host: www.cplusplus.com\r\n\r\n")` (note the double `\r\n\r\n` is on the last header only)