# Python convert html tags in ampersand format

Tags: python, text-to-html

I have text in the following format 
ampersand lt;div ampersand gt;\n ampersand lt;div ampersand gt; ampersand lt;span ampersand gt;Customer.. How can i convert this text to html i.e.

```
<div>
<div>
<span>
Customer..
```

Comment: See [htmlunescape](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml)

Comment: Writing something in "ampersand format" is called escaping, so what you are actually looking for is how to unescape HTML, which has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1

Comment: Thanks @DanielHepper. I didnt knew that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import html
html_string = "ampersand lt;div ampersand gt;\n ampersand lt;div ampersand gt; ampersand lt;span ampersand gt;Customer..".replace("ampersand ", "&")
html.unescape(html_string)
```

In case you are looking to maintain new lines:

```
html.unescape(html_string.replace("\n", "<br />"))
```