# Python - Check multiple white spaces in string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, whitespace

I am using this function to check if a string contains multiple white spaces:

```
def check_multiple_white_spaces(text):
    return "  " in text
```

and it is usually working fine, but not in this following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from string import punctuation

text = "<p>Hello &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;world!!</p>\r\n\r"

text = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser').text
text = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in set(punctuation))
text = text.lower().replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '')

print check_multiple_white_spaces(text)
```

The final value of `text` variable is `hello      world` , but I don't know why the `check_multiple_white_spaces` function is returning `False` instead of `True`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at what `print(repr(text))` shows... after you've run it through the soup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to print the contents of `text` using `repr()`, you will see that it does not contain two consecutive spaces:

```
'hello \xa0 \xa0 \xa0world '
```

As a result, your function correctly returns `False`. This could be fixed by converting the non-break space into a space:

```
text = text.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your function `check_multiple_white_spaces` cannot really check if there is multiple white spaces as there could be three white spaces or more.

You should use `re.search(r"\s{2,}", text)`.

Second, if you print `text`, you will find you need to unescape text.

See this answer.

[How do I unescape HTML entities in a string in Python 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1)

Comment: It is Python 2.x question. You need to pass `re.UNICODE` to the `re.search` method to match all Unicode whitespace chars with `\s`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right, I have been migrated to python3 for a long time. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no consecutive space in `text` variable, that’s why `check_multiple_white_spaces` function return `False` value.

```
>>> text
u'hello \xa0 \xa0 \xa0world '
>>> print text
hello      world
```

`\xa0` is no-break space, non-breakable space (NBSP), hard space.
Value os space is 32 and value of non-break space is 160

```
(u' ', 32)
(u'\xa0', 160)
```

The character \xa0 is a NO-BREAK SPACE, and the closest ASCII equivalent would of course be a regular space.

Use `unidecode module` to convert all non-ASCII characters to their closest ASCII equivalent

Demo:

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(text)
'hello      world '
>>> "  " in unidecode.unidecode(text)
True
```