# How to check multiple consecutive spaces in a string with python?

Tags: python, string

I want to find multiple spaces in a string using python. How to check if multiple spaces exist in a string?

```py
mystring = 'this   is a test'
```

I have tried the below code but it does not work.

```py
if bool(re.search(' +', ' ', mystring))==True:
    # ....
```

The result must return `True`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? Also, can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: did you mean to say "multiple consecutive spaces"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Check multiple white spaces in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360424/python-check-multiple-white-spaces-in-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` if you give no delimiter it will consider space as delimiter. after split check the length.If the length is greater than one it has spaces.

```
mystring = 'this   is a test'

if len(mystring.split()) > 1:
    #do something
```

Comment: OP want to find multiple spaces in a string. `len(mystring.split())` is > 1 even if `mystring` contains single spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use re and compare the strings like this:

```
import re

mystring = 'this  is a test'
new_str = re.sub(' +', ' ', mystring)


if mystring == new_str:
    print('There are no multiple spaces')
else:
    print('There are multiple spaces')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string.count() method:
If you want to check if multiple (more than one and no matter what their length) spaces exist the code is:

```
mystring.count(' ')>1
```

If you want to check if there is at least one consecutive space the code is:

```
mystring.count('  ')>=1
```

Comment: if that's what you want, just use `in`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you use for `re.search` is wrong. It should be `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`.

So, you can just do, searching for 2 or more spaces:

```
import re

def contains_multiple_spaces(s):
    return bool(re.search(r' {2,}', s))

contains_multiple_spaces('no multiple spaces')
# False

contains_multiple_spaces('here   are multiple spaces')
# True
```