# How to decode special currency characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, special-characters, decode, encode

How does one properly decode string values containing special currency characters?

Example:

```
&#3647; &#273;
```

I've been playing around with .encode() and .decode() methods, but with no success.

Comment: Python does not automatically recognize html escape sequences. You must use the `html` library to parse them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unescape HTML entities in a string in Python 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `html.unescape` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/html.html#html.unescape)):

```
from html import unescape

print(unescape('&#3647; &#273;'))
```

Prints:

```
฿ đ
```

Comment: For more information, read the Python 3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape

Comment: Oh duh. Thank you. I will accept this answer once possible.