# How to include "&" in XML file

Tags: python, xml, replace, escaping, xml-entities

I need the following output in an XML

`log="+ Passed Open the Website&#xD;&#xA;"`

Here is the relevant part of the code

```
var1 = '&#xD;&#xA;'
var2 = f' + {res} {na}{var1}'
var2 = var2.replace('&amp;', '&')
case = ET.SubElement(
    suite,
    "testcase",
    {
        "name": f"{na}",
        "log": f'{var2}'
```

I have tried `.replace` and escape but every time it shows this output.

`log=" + Passed Load Home Page&amp;#xD;&amp;#xA;"`

How can I replace the `&amp`  with `&`?

Comment: How did you implement the ```.replace``` function.

Comment: @Sujay added in the question. I tried many different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output is `&amp;#xD;&amp;#xA;` then it means that you are re-escaping.
Try to [unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360639/4607733) before outputing it, e.g.:

```
var1 = unescape('&#xD;&#xA;')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "missing"? `&#xD;&#xA;` represents just a newline.

Comment: Nope, see [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945)

Comment: In any case, it seems that your library is taking care of escaping for you, so you should not care of the syntax of your output.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
text = text.replace("&amp;", "&")
```

Comment: Doing that only, Don't know why it is not working.