# python: convert to HTML special characters

Tags: python, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace html entities with the corresponding utf-8 characters in Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730299/replace-html-entities-with-the-corresponding-utf-8-characters-in-python-2-6)
>   [What's the easiest way to escape HTML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python)

There is a way to easily convert a string to a HTML string,
e.g. with chars like <, > replaced by `&lt;`   `&gt;`
or will I have to write my own conversion routine???

Comment: see http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html#module-htmlentitydefs

Comment: I think what you need is called "HTML escaping". This is why you didn't find the answer by yourself. [Here is a Stackoverflow answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061697/whats-the-easiest-way-to-escape-html-in-python)

Comment: @TimPietzcker: oops... title doesn't really help ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're only concerned about critical special characters like `&`, `<` and `>`:

```
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape("<hello&goodbye>")
'&lt;hello&amp;goodbye&gt;'
```

For other non-ASCII characters:

```
>>> "Übeltäter".encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")
b'&#220;belt&#228;ter'
```

Of course, if necessary, you can combine the two:

```
>>> cgi.escape("<Übeltäter>").encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")
b'&lt;&#220;belt&#228;ter&gt;'
```

Comment: `>>> "Übeltäter".encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")` results in

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: `cgi.escape()` is now deprecated. Use `html.escape()` instead - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5072031/738017)