# Convert ascii characters to normal text

Tags: python, ascii

I have text like this:

```
&#8216;The zoom animations everywhere on the new iOS 7 are literally making me nauseous and giving me a headache,&#8217;wroteforumuser Ensorceled.
```

I understand that #8216 is an ASCII character.How can i convert it to normal characters without using .replace which is cumbersome.

Comment: &#8216; is a numeric entity.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730299/replace-html-entities-with-the-corresponding-utf-8-characters-in-python-2-6) relevant?

Comment: Nope that was asked in 08'. Please verify.

Comment: @user2784753: And what difference that *that* make? The answer still applies.

Comment: That particular numeric entity is not an ASCII character. ASCII only covers codes up to 127; above that is ISO 8859-1 (aka Latin 1) up to 255 and then ISO 10646 (pretty much Unicode).

Comment: @YannVernier: ASCII and Latin-1 are part of Unicode *too*. But that character is not ASCII, indeed.

Comment: Yes, but only the early parts. I apologize if I made that unclear. What I wanted to point out is that ASCII isn't sufficient for this character (opening single quote, the with &#8217; being closing single quote); this may make the question of converting it to "normal" characters rather complicated. Unicode is sufficient, so Python produces a unicode object (prefixed with u) in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have an HTML escape there. Use the [`HTMLParser.HTMLParser()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#HTMLParser.HTMLParser) to unescape these:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

parser = HTMLParser()
unescaped = parser.unescape(escaped)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> parser = HTMLParser()
>>> escaped = '&#8216;The zoom animations everywhere on the new iOS 7 are literally making me nauseous and giving me a headache,&#8217;wroteforumuser Ensorceled.'
>>> parser.unescape(escaped)
u'\u2018The zoom animations everywhere on the new iOS 7 are literally making me nauseous and giving me a headache,\u2019wroteforumuser Ensorceled.'
>>> print parser.unescape(escaped)
‘The zoom animations everywhere on the new iOS 7 are literally making me nauseous and giving me a headache,’wroteforumuser Ensorceled.
```

In Python 3, the `HTMLParser` module has been renamed to [`html.parser`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html); adjust the import accordingly:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```