# Unescaping HTML entities (&#nnnn;) into plain UTF-8

Tags: html, unix, utf-8

We have HTML source files which contain special characters encoded as `&#nnnn;` like in the word:

`au&#223;ergew&#246;hnlich`

We would like to convert them into plain UTF-8:

> außergewöhnlich

Is there any small tool to do that?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python

Comment: @uthark – That question asks for a solution using Python, which is not necessary for this conversion (and is a bit like killing a mosquito using a cannon). To compare: in my distribution the installed size of Python is 63348 KB; the size of Lynx is ‘only’ 3770 KB.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel Where are you getting these bull shit numbers?

Comment: @Evan – From my distribution's package manager (Arch Linux' Pacman). `pacman -Qi python` gives Python's installed size (among other things), `pacman -Qi lynx` does the same for Lynx, etc.

Comment: fascinating, that is totally useless.

Comment: This is a one-time conversion of HTML source files that contain numeric character entity references to files that contain actual UTF-8 encoded characters, correct? Who cares how big the tool is?
Evan's perl or uthark's ascii2uni seem like fine answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose [ascii2uni](http://billposer.org/Software/uni2ascii.html) tool will perform required conversion.

The size of the tool is about several hundreds kilobytes, it is smaller than lynx, mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with perl, and [`HTML::Entities`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.65/lib/HTML/Entities.pm) if you wish.

```
echo 'echo 'au&#223;ergew&#246;hnlich' |
perl -MHTML::Entities -pe'binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"; HTML::Entities::decode_entities($_)'
```

Comment: Again, shooting a mosquito… Perl occupies 45796 KB here.

Comment: But this works, and `lynx -dump` fails.

Comment: Perl occupies 45meg? That sounds like a mighty ridiculous claim. The binary is 1.2MB. Running that there is 2.3MB resident.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full shell solution (apparently you don't specify the 'language' to be used).

```
foo='au&#223;ergew&#246;hnlich'
echo "$foo"

au&#223;ergew&#246;hnlich

eval "$(printf '%s' "$foo" | sed 's/^/printf "/;s/&#0*\([0-9]*\);/\$( [ \1 -lt 128 ] \&\& printf "\\\\$( printf \"%.3o\\201\" \1)" || \$(which printf) \\\\u\$( printf \"%.4x\" \1) )/g;s/$/\\n"/')" | sed "s/$(printf '\201')//g"

außergewöhnlich
```

Comment: this work ALSO with dash (used as standard shell for Ubuntu). We must use the GNU printf in some places because the builtin printf in dash does not know \u to convert to Unicode. Also, the GNU printf is kind of stupid, as it refuses to work with codepoints from 0 to 127 which are perfectly legal in UTF. Thus we have to make is conditionnal and use octal for the range 0-128.
The last sed is used in case you need to convert characters like Line Feed (
) or Tab (	). We use a trick so that the command substition keeps these trailing characters, then we remove the "trick" with the last sed. The character used for that should NOT happen if your input conforms to Unicode, so it should be safe.