# How do I get rid of characters like &#x27; that appear instead of apostrophes?

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert XML/HTML Entities into Unicode String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)

I am attempting to scrape a website using Python. I import and use the urllib2, BeautifulSoup and re modules.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
responseString = str(soup)

coarseExpression = re.compile('<div class="sodatext">[\n]*.*[\n]*</div>')
coarseResult = coarseExpression.findall(responseString)

fineExpression = re.compile('<[^>]*>')
fineResult = []

for coarse in coarseResult:
    fine = fineExpression.sub('', coarse) 
    #print(fine)
    fineResult.append(fine)
```

Unfortunately, characters like apostrophes appear in a corrupted manner like so - &#x27 ;
Is there a way to avoid this? Or a way to replace them easily?

Comment: That's not corrupted, that's the HTML/XML character entity for an apostrophe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).  You could always decode such entities back to their ASCII equivalents. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)

Comment: You are loading a page in BeautifulSoup **JUST TO REGEX IT!?** Why are you doing this awful, awful thing?!

Comment: @FrancisAvila, I'm still feeling my way around Python. Could you tell me a better way?

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup to search or walk through the HTML tree and get what you need. That's why it exists in the first place! Read the BeautifulSoup documentation.

Comment: Open a new question with what you are trying to do as a whole. I suspect you are fixated on using regexes when in reality that is exactly the *wrong* tool to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 5):

The following BeautifulSoup documentation on entity conversion should be what you're looking for:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Entity%20Conversion

Comment: Just to point out that BS can't decode hex encoded entities (`&#x27;`), but it works well with decimal encoded entities (`&#39;`). So, OP needs to convert them beforehand.

Comment: @Avaris That sounds like a bug, or at least a missing feature, in BS, TBH.