# Decoding querystring parameter in Django view

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a search form in my app that uses a jQuery autocomplete plugin. The plugin sends over the suggested item after running the querystring through `encodeURI(q)`.

So an item like **Johnny's sports** comes to my view as `Johnny&#39;s sports`

How do I decode the string back to **Johnny's Sports** so I can query the database?

I've tried several `urllib` functions that have been suggested in other posts but I think I'm seriously misunderstanding how they work because I'm not seeing it work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's standardlib contains the `HTMLParser`. It can perform decoding of escaped HTML entities, as noted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/145400

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> print h.unescape('Johnny&#39;s sports')
Johnny's sports
```

Answer (score 0):

You might give the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python) a try. Seems to do what you need.