# Change &#39 into normal character

Tags: python, html, character-encoding

I'm having trouble displaying content,
my program:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import urllib
import re

url = "http://yahoo.com"
pattern = '''<span class="medium item-label".*?>(.*)</span>'''

website = urllib.urlopen(url)
pageContent = website.read()
result = re.findall(pattern, pageContent)

for record in result:
    print record
```

output:

```
Masked teen killed by dad
First look in &#39;Hotel of Doom&#39;
Ex-NFL QB&#39;s sad condition
Reporter ignores warning
Romney&#39;s low bar for debates
```

So the question is what should I include in my code in order to transform &#39 into characters

Comment: maybe duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Python2:

```
In [16]: text = 'Ex-NFL QB&#39;s sad condition'

In [17]: import HTMLParser

In [18]: parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()

In [19]: parser.unescape(text)
Out[19]: u"Ex-NFL QB's sad condition"
```

In Python3:

```
import html.parser as htmlparser
parser = htmlparser.HTMLParser()
parser.unescape(text)
```

Comment: `html.parser.HTMLParser.unescape` is deprecated, and `html.unescape` should be used instead. Abhishek's answer is more up-to-date.

Answer (score 11):

The solution for Python 3,

```
import html
html.unescape(text)
```