# python - possible encoding and decoding values

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to decode chatacters which have been encoded in the following way:
&#number;
I tried:

```
 s.decode("utf8")
```

and:

```
 s.decode("unicode-escape")
```

but both not seems to work.

What is the encoding I should use to decode this kind?

In general - where can I find a list of all valid encodings?

Comment: See also [Convert XML HTML entities into Unicode string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python **2**:

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print h.unescape('&pound;682m')
£682m
```

Python **3**:

```
import html.parser
h = html.parser.HTMLParser()
print(h.unescape('&pound;682m'))
£682m
```

.encode and .decode works in a little bit different way then you expect i'm afraid.
See the following:

```
print 'å'.decode('iso-8859-1')
u'\x86'
```

The string were encoded in latin-1 when i inputted it into the console (`å`) but my end-point uses iso-8859-1 so i can re-encode it to fit my endpoint's character encoding.

For more info in character encodings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but I was asking about translating back something in the format: &#(some_number); what you provided doesn't work for that

Comment: `&#number;` -> `symbol`, it's also true to do `symbol` -> `&#number;` via `h.escape()` obviously. Your question was that you **had** a &#number and wanted to "decode" it, that's what my solution does.. ask your question correct if you want another answer but as i mentioned, you can do this in reverse and get the oposite.

Comment: sorry! you were right. your code do works. I have other problem while trying to write it into a file but that's a whole other story.