# Simple example BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was working a simple example with BeautifulSoup, but I was getting weird resutls.

Here is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup.prettify()
stuff = soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class' : 'prodSpecAtribtue'})
print stuff
```

When I print I get:

```
[]
```

Not sure what's happening, because when I printed soup on the screen I got proper data. Basically I am searching for values in found in tag `<td>` under class `prodSpecAtribtue`

Comment: No, you would either get `[]` or a list with matches. You would **not** get `{}`.

Comment: Sorry, this gives me {}

Comment: Can you show us some sample HTML snippet that still produces this result?

Comment: Ah, you changed it to `.findAll()` (from `.find()` before).

Comment: You do realize that you misspelled `prodSpecAtribtue`, right? I'd expect it to be spelled `prodSpecAttribute` instead.

Comment: Is this BeautifulSoup 3 or 4?

Comment: http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1

Comment: @MartijnPieters its version 3

Comment: There is **no** `prodSpecAttribute` *or* `prodSpecAtribtue` class anywhere in that document. There is not even a `<td>`.

Comment: When I print the result of `soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class' : 'prodSpecAtribtue'})` I get `[]` (not `{}`), or the empty list, which is expected as there are not `<td>` elements anywhere on the page you linked to.

Comment: The page uses AJAX queries to fill the table dynamically. Use your browser developer tools to detect what URLs are being requested asynchronously, then load *those*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm really stupid, I gave the wrong link. This is the correct one:http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/stir/eurodollar_contract_specifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the class name:

```
soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'prodSpecAtribute'})
```

works fine. That's `prodSpecAtribute`, *not* `prodSpecAtribtue`. That's still misspelled, but slightly less so.

Comment: Do you know an efficient way from using BeautifulSoup to extract data of the format: <td colspan="5"> and <td colspan="4">. I figured regex is the simplest solution.

Comment: @JamesHallen: Pick out all `td` with a colspan attribute: `.findAll('td', colspan=True)`, pick out all `td` with a colspan attribute with values 4 *or* 5: `.findAll('td', colspan=['4', '5'])`

Comment: Having a bit of trouble, using the same idea, I should be able to get all the data inside the tages `<td colspan="5">` using `soup = BeautifulSoup(page)` `stuff = soup.findAll('td', colspan = ['4', '5'])`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @JamesHallen: That `.findall()` returns all matching `td` elements. To get the text data *inside* of those elements, use `.string` on each element..

Comment: I use something like: `elements = stuff.getText()`, and I use a regex expression to get rid of some unwanted elements: `elements = re.sub('&\w+;', '', elements)`, do you think this is a good idea?

Comment: @JamesHallen: For BeautifulSoup 3, you want to use `.findAll(text=True)` to find all text instead, perhaps joining the result with `' '.join(stuff.findAll(text=True))`.

Comment: @JamesHallen: BeautifulSoup 3 is not that great at replacing `&...;` html entities with their proper Unicode codepoints. Upgrade to BeautifulSoup 4, or [convert them manually afterwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python).

Comment: I can't use `.findAll(text=True)` along with `.findall('td', colspan = [...])` right?

Comment: @JamesHallen: Sure you can. Loop over the elements from the `findAll('td'..)`, each element you find you can call `.findAll(text=True)` on:  `for cell in soup.findAll('td', colspan = ['4', '5']): print ' '.join(cell.findAll(text=True))`.

Comment: If you don't mind, I don't really understand how your `' '.join(cell.findAll())` works. We use `' '.join` to append strings, so what are we appending here?

Comment: @JamesHallen: `cell.findAll(text=True)` returns a sequence of text. `' '.join()` joins that sequence into one long string.

Comment: so somehing like `"this" "is" "a" "string"` will become `"this is is a string"`

Comment: @JamesHallen: Something like `this <i>is a <b>HTML-formatted</b></i> string` becomes `"this is a HTML-formatted string"`; the `.findAll(text=True)` call finds all text elements, recursively.