# Convert HTML entity to iOS Emoji?

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I am getting HTML entity from server as JSON response example `&#128513;` => 😁 , now i wish to show this emoji on my button. if i receive unicode for emoji it's works fine simply placing setting button title but it's not works in-case of HTML entity emoji.

```
 button.setTitle(emoticon_icon, for: .normal)
```

so my question is how can i convert HTML entity into unicode for respective emoji.

similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57708/3145189) is asked for python but couldn't found for iOS.