# Decoding html entities in python2

Tags: python, utf-8

I have a string of escaped html markup , `'&#xed;'`, and I want it to the correct accented character `'í'`.

Having read around SO, this is my attempt:

```
messy = '&#xed;'
print type(messy)
>>> <type 'str'>

decoded=messy.decode('utf-8')
print decoded
>>> &#xed;
```

Drats. After reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224/getting-international-characters-from-a-web-page#53246), I tried this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
soup = BeautifulSoup(messy, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
print soup.contents[0].string
>>> &#xed;
```

Still not working, so I tested the example from the SO question I linked to previously.

```
html = '&#196;'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
print soup.contents[0].string
>>> Ä
```

This one works. Does anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HTMLParser.HTMLParser.unescape`:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> parser.unescape('&#xed;')
u'\xed'
>>> print parser.unescape('&#xed;')
í
```

In Python 3.x:

```
>>> import html.parser
>>> parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
>>> parser.unescape('&#xed;')
'í'
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does the BS solution work for '&#196;' but not '&#xed;'?

Comment: @user2958776, It seems like BS doesn't convert hexadecimal form html entities. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/57745/2225682) is workaround for that.

Comment: @user2958776, Post another separated question.